# how to design applications to run on different cloud providers?

Tags: architecture, interop, cloud

I am trying to design an application which will run on the cloud. The application will offer a a service through API. And I want it to be provider-independent i.e. to work on any cloud provider without changing my application.

The application will create/manage virtual machine instances and execute some computations (on the IaaS level) and this will be usually done through the provider's specific API. But as a feature, I want the application to be portable to different cloud providers without chaging the implementation.

How would I design for such an abstraction? 
I thought of creating adapters for each provider, but I doubt that this is the best way of doing it.

P.S.: I found some multi-cloud libraries like [jCloud](http://jclouds.apache.org/) which provide some features that works across multiple providers.

Answer (score 2):

JClould will certainly help you to design your application independently, for example, of the file system you plan to use. Instead of using Amazon S3 for storing your application data, you could use another provider without doing a lot of modification on your application side. Maybe just your credential and the new service you are going to use.

However, since you plan to use the cloud. I think that it is also important to use some Cloud Patterns on your applications design. For example:

- File System is ephermal for multi-tenant applications on the cloud (not persistent file system).
- Singletons
- Latency

You have some information about this on these [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ndeloof/cloud-patterns-j1) about Cloud Patterns. I hope it could help you to understand better the way in which you should design your application.